# How do I pull out only the content within the body tag of an ajax response that contains an entire HTML page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: rootPath + "Framework/GetPartial",
            data: { partialName: partialName },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response)
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#partialContent').hide().html(response).fadeIn();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#partialContent').hide().html('An error occurred. Details below:<br /><br />' + xhr.responseText).fadeIn();
            }
        });
```

What I am concerned with is the error handling function. When an error occurs on the server an html page is sent as the response containing detailed debug information. I would like to load this html response into the existing page, but the inclusion of the `<HTML>`, `<HEAD>`, and `<BODY>` tags in the response ruins the formatting of the entire page. How would I parse out just the content in the body tag using JQuery in the following HTML response?

```
<html>

    <head>

        <title>The method or operation is not implemented.</title>

        <style>

         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 

         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }

         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }

         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}

         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}

         .version {color: gray;}

         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}

         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

        </style>

    </head>



    <body bgcolor="white">



            <span><H1>Server Error in '/AlexAndNikki' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>



            <h2> <i>The method or operation is not implemented.</i> </h2></span>



            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">



            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



            <br><br>



            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.<br><br>



            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>



            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">

               <tr>

                  <td>

                      <code><pre>



Line 19:         public PartialViewResult GetPartial(string partialName)

Line 20:         {

<font color=red>Line 21:             throw new NotImplementedException();

</font>Line 22:             //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

Line 23:             if (!ViewExists(partialName))</pre></code>



                  </td>

               </tr>

            </table>



            <br>



            <b> Source File: </b> C:\Users\alex.ford\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AlexAndNikki\AlexAndNikki\Controllers\FrameworkController.cs<b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Line: </b> 21

            <br><br>



            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>



            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">

               <tr>

                  <td>

                      <code><pre>



[NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.]

   AlexAndNikki.Controllers.FrameworkController.GetPartial(String partialName) in C:\Users\alex.ford\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AlexAndNikki\AlexAndNikki\Controllers\FrameworkController.cs:21

   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127

   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +258

   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39

   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassd.&lt;InvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__a() +125

   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640

   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +312

   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +709

   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162

   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__4() +58

   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__0() +20

   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +453

   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +371

</pre></code>



                  </td>

               </tr>

            </table>



            <br>



            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>



            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1



            </font>



    </body>

</html>

<!-- 

[NotImplementedException]: The method or operation is not implemented.

   at AlexAndNikki.Controllers.FrameworkController.GetPartial(String partialName) in C:\Users\alex.ford\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AlexAndNikki\AlexAndNikki\Controllers\FrameworkController.cs:line 21

   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )

   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()

   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()

   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

-->
```

**EDIT:**

Would there be a way to load the response string into an iframe? This would be wonderful if it was possible.

Something like:

```
$('#partialContent').html('<iframe>' + xhr.responseText + '</iframe>');
```

Obviously I tried this code and it didn't work, but maybe someone knows how to make an iframe solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own question.......again. This is only my second question and both times I just spent hours googling and came up with the answer on my own. Sorry guys! I really wanted to accept someone's answer.

Anyway, the easiest solution I found was to load the response string containing the html into an iframe dynamically. Here is an example:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#partialContent').html('<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: solid 1px #000000;" id="errorFrame"></iframe>');
                var myFrame = $('#errorFrame')[0]; //top.frames['errorFrame'];
                myFrame = myFrame.contentWindow || myFrame.contentDocument.document || myFrame.contentDocument;
                myFrame.document.open();
                myFrame.document.write(xhr.responseText);
                myFrame.document.close();
            }
```

If you have a need for this solution just remember that you have to account for good ol' IE and its failure to follow W3C standards. contentWindow is IE's equivalent to contentDocument. As long as you include `myFrame = myFrame.contentWindow || myFrame.contentDocument.document || myFrame.contentDocument;` you'll be fine.

Here is a sample of the error page loaded into an iframe:
http://67.2.141.90/AlexAndNikki/Framework/GenerateError

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: +1 That would work. FYI, you should be able to shorten the code for assigning `myFrame` since the test and the assigned value are the same. You could use a logical OR `||` operator like this: `myFrame = myFrame.contentWindow || myFrame.contentDocument.document || myFrame.contentDocument;` It will assign the first one it finds.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#partialContent').hide().html($('body',response).contents()).fadeIn();
```

This is a shortcut for `.empty().append()` underneath, but the main portion is `$('body',response)`, which is looking for a `<body>` element in the response, then taking it's contents as the elements to append.

Comment: I tried this. All that is printed to the page is `[object Object]`

Comment: This will fail in some browsers. Safari (for example) strips out everything except for the content of the `<body>`.

Comment: @Chevex - Give this a try instead: `var b = $('body',response).contents(); $('#partialContent').hide().html(b.length ? b : response).fadeIn();` (sorry, not used to returning full pages for use here).

Comment: All your expression did was return the response as it is right now, HTML tags intact.

Comment: @Chevex - ...that shouldn't be the case at all, which browser? (`.innerHTML` varies by browser) and what does `alert($('body',response).contents().length)` give you?

Comment: `var b = $('body', xhr.responseText).contents();` contains nothing so `b.length ? b : xhr.responseText` evaluates b.length, finds it undefined, and returns the raw `xhr.responseText` to be dumped into the page. No different than if I just did `xhr.responseText` without the b variable.

Comment: Also, is contents() a jquery method? I've never seen that before. I've only ever seen html() and text().

Comment: @Chevex - yup it's there, http://api.jquery.com/contents/, what does `alert($(xhr.responseText).html())` give?

Comment: @Chevex - Which browser?  As we're said several times in comment here it depends on the browser, but you never mentioned which one you're using :)

Comment: All 3 browsers. IE, FF, Chrome

Comment: Why would this depend on the browser. It is JQuery handling the response string and JQuery does not have gaping cross-browser issues such as this. Besides, I am testing all solutions in all 3 major browsers as you guys offer them.

Comment: @Chevex - It does very much depend on the browser...do you have a test page? I'm unable to replicate your results, but I'm not sure if that comment at the end is throwing things off.  This is all `.innerHTML` depending, and it *definitely* varies per browser, there are dozens of SO questions on this.

Comment: All I'm doing is manually throwing an exception on the server that responds to the ajax call. This makes ASP.NET MVC respond with a fully-formed html page which is placed in the xhr object under the responseText property. If I drop this responseText into the page it works fine. The only issue is the inclusion of the fully-formed HTML tags.

Comment: I could not find any other questions on this or I would not have asked it. Can you please link me?

Answer (score 1):

var content = $('body').html(); //gives you the content of the body

Comment: You are not understanding the question. That gives me the body of the page the script is running on. I want the body within the XHR response of the ajax request. `xhr.responseText`

Comment: $('body',xhr.responseText).html();

Comment: there's another way to which is to create a hidden iframe and set the html of the iframe to the reposense text, the use $('body',iframe).html();

Comment: I already tried `$('body', xhr.responseText).html();` unfortunately that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers deal with full HTML pages differently. You should really only return the content you want.

If that's not a possibility, this will look for the `<body>` at different levels, depending on which tags the browser has stripped away.

```
var $response = $( response );

var $content = (( $response.children('body').length ) ? $response.children('body').contents() :
               ( $response.filter('body').length ) ? $response.filter('body').contents() :
               $response).not('style,title,script');

$('#partialContent').hide().html( $content ).fadeIn();
```

No guarantees, but it may help a bit.

---

**EDIT:** Didn't notice you're dealing with the error callback, and trying to concatenate the HTML. My answer above will result in `[object Object]` for the concatenation.

Use the code above, except use this when adding the response to the `partialContent`.

```
var $response = $( response );

var $content = (( $response.children('body').length ) ? $response.children('body').contents() :
               ( $response.filter('body').length ) ? $response.filter('body').contents() :
               $response).not('style,title,script');

$('#partialContent').hide().html('An error occurred. Details below:<br /><br />' +  
                      $('<div>').append( $content ).html()).fadeIn();
```

**EDIT:** Added code to strip out `<title>`, `<style>` and `<script>` tags since some browsers also give you the content of the `<head>`.

Comment: I know I should be returning only what I need. In the event of success it does this. Only on failure does this error response come back. I can dump it into the page it just screws up the markup.

Comment: @Chevex - I didn't look closely enough, and didn't realize we were dealing with the `error:` callback. I'll update in a minute.

Comment: Yeah, because the error response comes back as a fully-formed HTML page, dropping the response string into the page messes with a lot of the formatting of the page. If I could pull the body contents from the response then I could just drop those onto the page and it would work just fine.

Comment: @Chevex - It just gets a little tricky because of different browser behavior. I updated my answer so that it is adding an HTML string instead of DOM elements. Otherwise you get `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thank you. I am leaving work and will try this out as soon as I reach home.

Comment: @Chavex - Let me know how it goes. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/mH9Kq/) of my edited answer.

Comment: Hmmm, this seems to load content but the head contents are still there. I'm thinking this is more trouble than it's worth. Would it be possible to load these contents in an iFrame somehow? There is no physical html file to load, only a response string so I don't know how that would work.

Comment: I solved the issue on my own with lots of googling about iframes and javascript. See my answer for the solution. Thanks for the help! Sorry I can't accept yours :(

Comment: @Chevex - That's alright. Anyway, I didn't realize that Firefox gave you both the content of the `head` and `body`. To make this work, I'd need to strip unwanted elements out before doing the append. `$content.not('style,title,script')`